# Difference between "Clean cookie each iteration" and "User Thread group configuration to control cookie"

Tags: jmeter

Can any one share difference between "Clean cookie each iteration" and "User Thread group configuration to control cookie" in Http Cookie manger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) there is a setting: `Same user on each iteration`

[image]

- if the box is "ticked" - the HTTP Cookie Manager will re-use the cookies from t previous iteration so JMeter thread (virtual user) will be considered a "returning" one.
- if the box is not ticked - the HTTP Cookie Manager will clean all cookies on each iteration of the Thread Group so the user will be "new"

So you have the choice whether to "respect" the Thread Group settings or control the cookies on the HTTP Cookie Manager level.

The same behaviour is applicable for the [HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager/)