# What is the relation between "same user on each thread" and Number of Threads in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

My understanding is that on **checking** the box "same user on each thread" the cookies are not cleaned up after each request. But if I specify 200 threads  then are all the 200 threads using the same cookies? Ideally I would like the 200 threads to represent different users and therefore use different cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter's cookies and [cache](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), etc. are **local to the thread**, each thread will have it's own cookies, you can verify it yourself using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script).

- If you check the box - the cookies and cache will not be cleared, i.e. on each [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration you will get the "same user"
- If you don't check the box - the cookies and cache will be cleared, i.e. on each Thread Group iteration you will get "returning user" who is already logged in and has full cache of embedded resources

Comment: In your second point you say "the cookies and cache will be cleared" but then go on to say " 'returning user' who is already logged in and has full cache of embedded resources". How does  the returning user have full cache and embedded resources if the cookies and cache are cleared?

Comment: A similar answer that Dmitri posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70830433/132374